# Naming the project in Wakatime from Sublime 2

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, projects-and-solutions

How to name my project in Wakatime ([www.wakatime.com](https://www.wakatime.com))?

It is showing up as unanmed project and I am working from Sublime Text Editor 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Project -> Save Project As`. Keep in mind that in ST, a project is simply a collection of folders. Of course, you can create some project specific settings and what not, but just pointing this out in case you were expecting some specific behavior as a Wakatime project. Then again, you may have a plugin that is doing some stuff for you.

More info at https://wakatime.com/help/faq/general#set-project-name

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Project -> Save Project As`. That way WakaTime will use the project you set in Sublime Text.

Alternatively, instead of using Sublime Text projects WakaTime will use a Git/Mercurial/Svn folder as the project's name.

This [WakaTime FAQ Answer](https://wakatime.com/faq#rename-projects) explains the various ways to set a project's name in your WakaTime dashboard, and how to rename a WakaTime project if needed.